# how to install a .rpm file on Intel Edison?

Tags: linux, yocto, intel-edison

Hi I am new to Linux and I am trying to install a .rpm file on an Intel Edison but I can't find a way to install it, I have tried:

```
rpm -i filename.rpm
```

With this command I get the error "Failed dependencies: /bin/bash is needed", "/bin/sh is needed" and some more, both of thise files exist. This is also the result with all other commands that tries to install the file.

further information the Linux is based on Yocto, and from what I understand there is no command like "apt-get".

So my question is, how to install a .rpm file on an Intel Edison?

Answer (score 1):

Although I have only worked with Galileo, they share a lot of tricks with the Edison family of boards:

1. To install additional packages (a la apt-get), try the `opkg` command. If not available, try updating your system image.
2. If you do have `bash` and or `sh`, symlink them to the needed folder:

   - `$ which bash` will give you the location of bash, `/usr/bin/bash`, for example.
   - Take that folder, and add a symlink: `ln -s /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash`. Remember to replace `/usr/bin/bash` with the output of the previous command.

Answer (score 0):

Edison is dual core atom, I would suggest you to put CentOS on it and then try to install a rpm on it.

Comment: The cores are indeed Atom Silvermonts but the rest is still typical embedded hardware: it won't work with a vanilla kernel and one doesn't just "put CentOS on it" (I'm sure it can be done but it's going to be quite a bit more involved than a normal install).